# Convertir dd/MM/yyyy a yyyy/MM/dd

Tags: vb.net

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Me.txtFechaFin.Text = '08/03/2018'
```

alguien me puede decir como lo puedo convertir a

```
Me.txtFechaFin.Text = '2018/03/08'
```

Comment: Lo quieres convertir desde vb o sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no recuerdo mal puedes hacerlo con la propiedad `Format`.

Prueba algo como esto en tu código:

```
Me.txtFechaFin.Text = Format(Me.txt.FechaFin.Text, "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

Conviértelo a un objeto DateTime, y luego vuelves a una cadena de texto, así:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Me.txtFechaFin.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Me.txtFechaFin.Text =  myDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```